# How do I get the name of an SQLAlchemy object's primary key?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I just want to programatically determine the name of an SQLalchemy model's primary key.

Comment: If this solution works for you, it's completely acceptable to add your solution as an answer and mark it as "answered". This helps for when people are looking for unanswered questions.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If using SQLAlchemy version 0.8 or later, you should use the [runtime inspection API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html#sqlalchemy.inspection.inspect).

If the model class is `User` and the sole primary key is `id`,

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
>>> inspect(User).primary_key[0].name
'id'
```

If the model class is `User` and there are many primary keys,

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
>>> [key.name for key in inspect(User).primary_key]
['id', 'name']
```

If using SQLAlchemy version less than 0.8, you should use the `class_mapper()` function instead.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper
>>> class_mapper(User).primary_key[0].name
'id'
```

In this case, the `inspect()` function and the `class_mapper()` function return the same object, but using `inspect()` is more future-proof.

Comment: I know this is really old answer but it should be noted, all of the above return the column names which are not necessarily going to match the class property names. Mapper also has a method `get_property_by_column` which can be used to access the `ColumnProperty` object corresponding to the column in the primary key. `ColumnProperty` in turn gives you access to `key`, the name of the property, `class_attribute` to access the class `InstrumentedAttribute`, etc.

Answer (score 9):

If class is "User", and there is just 1 primary key, do this*:

```
User.__mapper__.primary_key._list[0].name
```

---

<sup>*</sup><sub>Moved from the question.</sub>

Comment: Or if you need all the primary keys you can do the list comprehension stated above: `[k.name for k in User.__mapper__.primary_key]`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the declarative model class is `User`,

```
>>> list(User.__table__.primary_key)[0].name
'id'
```

Or for `Membership` which has a composite primary key

```
>>> [pk.name for pk in Membership.__table__.primary_key]
['user_id', 'group_id']
```

Comment: Not sure why this has a negative vote when it works.

Answer (score 1):

For **SQLAlchemy version 2.0**, if you wish to know a table's primary key column name you will need to use `inspect(table).primary_key.columns.values()[0].name` as follows:

```
>>> metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
>>> from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
>>> for table in metadata.sorted_tables:
>>>     if len(inspect(table).primary_key.columns.values()) > 0:
>>>          print("Table " + table.name + "'s primary key column is " + inspect(table).primary_key.columns.values()[0].name
Table x's primary key column is 'id'
Table y's primary key column is 'id' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
a=inspect(TheModelInstance)
a=a.mapper.primary_key
print(a)
```