# How to copy sqlalchemy models in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a mechanism of duplicating sqlalchemy models in flask. To do so, I'm running the following logic:

```
class Model:
      primitive_type = (int, bool, float, str)
      def copy(self):
          copy = type(self)()
          for key, val in self.__dict__.items():
              if not key.startswith('_') and isinstance(val, Model.primitive_type):
                 copy.__setattr__(key, val)
          return copy
```

Then I've a model named sensor which is an abstract model:

```
class Sensor(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'sensor'

     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     device_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('device.id'))
     type = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)

     __mapper_args__ = {
         'polymorphic_identity': 'sensor',
         'polymorphic_on': type
     }
```

And finally I've the sensor itself which ineriths both from **Model** and **Sensor**:

```
class Pnt(Model, Sensor):
     __tablename__ = 'pnt'

     id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sensor.id'), primary_key=True)
     host_ip = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, info={'label': "Ip"})
     ...
     def copy(self):
         copy = super().copy()
         return copy
```

The problem is that super().copy() returns the values from Sensor and not from Pnt. This method isn't working only in this case.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tried to reproduce it and come to a different result. What is missing? Is the host_ip attribute missing? What do you intend to do with the copy? Do you just want to save a copy in the database?

Comment: Thank you @Detlef. Yes the host_ip is missing. I have not any attribute of Pnt. Yes I want to duplicate Pnt and insert it in database with a new id.

Comment: As I said, I have the Pnt attributes with your code. Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871406/how-to-clone-a-sqlalchemy-db-object-with-new-primary-key) example especially the top answer. I think it's an excellent solution.