# Database restful API : how to describe table structure

Tags: rest, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm currently working on a javascript (react based) app that basically displays data from some database's tables, and allows to add, delete, update data from the tables. I implemented the services to access the database using Flask and SQLAlchemy, trying to follow the REST specification (more as a guideline than a 'dogma', since I'm not sharing my API over internet).

I want to implement a web-service that describes each table: let's take the table below

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

I want that kind of thing:

GET /user/description

Response: something like

```
[
{column_name: 'id', type: 'int'  , p_key: 'True'},
{column_name: 'username', type: 'string'},
{column_name: 'email', type: 'string'}
]
```

(plus other useful metadata for a client willing to insert or  update data)

I would like to know if there's such a kind of operation in the REST specification, and if not where can I find guidelines for implementing such a service (the dos and don'ts) - I would rather not reinvent the wheel for something that looks to me like a fairly common problem in programming.

Comment: Try taking a look at this?https://www.flaskapi.org/

Answer (score 0):

Ok first what you need is an indicator, so you need to check what's the client want to view (for e.g the first user so id=0/1) send an ajax request for example or a form or whatever you want to this path:

```
@app.route("/user/description", methods=[...])
```

Now what you need to do is to filter the data by the ID you got so

`username = User.query.filter(User.id).all()[0].username # etc`

get the type of the `username` by doing `type(username)` and put all of this data into a dict to send the JSON response(do what I just showed you for every column). If you want to find if the column has a primary key I suggest you'll watch [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745189/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-sqlalchemy-objects-primary-key):

Comment: Thanks for answering. But my question is not 'how to implement it', I'm looking for a specification telling what the response of the service should be. For the now I'm writing a home cooked API.

Comment: What do you mean it needs to be in JSON format, dict in Python.  Can you maybe elaborate?